# UITableView grouped displaying new info in every section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I have an array of reviews which I am outputing into a grouped table. I want each review to be in its own tableview section when I sent the sections method to [array count] it just repeats the same group for as many items are in the array. Any idea's how I can do this? I hope it makes sense. Thanks

--EDIT--

Added a picture of what I want to achieve and the cellForRow/Section/DidSelectRowMethod's 
I hope this clarify's everything

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }


    cell.primaryLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"comment"];

    if([[object objectForKey:@"rating"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rating_0.png"];
    }
    if([[object objectForKey:@"rating"] isEqualToString:@"1"])    {
        cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rating_1.png"];
    }
    if([[object objectForKey:@"rating"] isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rating_2.png"];
    }
    if([[object objectForKey:@"rating"] isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rating_3.png"];
    }
    if([[object objectForKey:@"rating"] isEqualToString:@"4"])
    {
        cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rating_4.png"];
    }
    if([[object objectForKey:@"rating"] isEqualToString:@"5"])
    {
        cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rating_5.png"];
    }


    return cell;

}


// Override if you need to change the ordering of objects in the table.
- (PFObject *)objectAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
    return [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Review *review = [[Review alloc] initWithNibName:@"Review" bundle:nil];
    review.Name = [object objectForKey:@"userId"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[object objectForKey:@"userId"]);
    review.rating = [object objectForKey:@"rating"];
    review.comments = [object objectForKey:@"comment"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:review animated:YES];

    [review release];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return [self.objects count];
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code so that question will become more clear.

Comment: As a sidenote... You could replace all your `if` statements with: `cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rating_%@.png", [object objectForKey:@"rating"]]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want every review to be in a separate group you have to use index path's section instead of the row for the array index (the row will always be 0 since you only have one row per section):

```
// Override if you need to change the ordering of objects in the table.
- (PFObject *)objectAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
    return [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return 1 for the numberOfRowsFor every section.
Add my given code in your code

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return 1;
 }
```

This means that every section has only 1 cell or row. I hope that this is what you want to achieve. (Each review will now have it's own section)

Comment: This means that every section has only 1 cell or row. I hope that this is what you want to achieve. (Each review will now have it's own section)